# Unexpected end in functions.php file - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, unexpectendoffile

I have been dealing with this issue all day long, and I have no idea how to remedy it.
I have searched for the issue on SO and have found my problem has occured to other people here. I have tried to the best of my ability to follow the steps that people have suggested to them but it still seems that I am getting the following error on my page:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /hermes/waloraweb015/b1446/as.allthingsnetwork/blog/wp-content/themes/atn/functions.php on line 56

Through researching, I understand that error means that there are brackets that haven't been closed or missing ';' in the file. I have tried to fix those issues to no avail, so I'm here to post my code and possibly get a response from someone who is kind enough to help out.

**functions.php:**

```
<?php
// Enable support for post-thumbnails

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

if ( function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}

function wpbeginner_remove_comment_url($arg) {
    $arg['url'] = '';
    return $arg;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'wpbeginner_remove_comment_url');


function wpbeginner_comment_text_after($arg) {
    $arg['comment_notes_before'] = "Let us know if you like this track</a>!";
    return $arg;
}

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'wpbeginner_comment_text_after');

  function custom_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {

       $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>

       <div class="alignleft">
       <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_ID()); ?>
       </div>

        <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="comment-intro">
                <h3><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()); ?></h3>
                <a class="comment-permalink" href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s'), get_comment_date()); ?>
            </a>
            <em> | </em>
            <a class="comment-permalink" href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>">
                <?php comment_time(); ?> 
            </a>
            </div>

            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                <em><php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em><br />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="comment-text">
            <?php comment_text(); ?>
            </div><br />

            <div class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))); ?>
            </div>

}
?>
```

Thank you so much in advance to anyone that is willing to help me out,
Anthony.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Prix, this solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end you have:

```
}
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Here

```
<php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.'); ?>
```

And finally here, note you have it like this twice:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars ( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>
```

Comment: It's worth noting the first bit (i.e. `<?php } ?>`) is what's causing the error. The rest is just best practices.

Comment: @NickQ. nope, in some cases if u don't properly close your echo's it will produce errors as well. [See here a very simple example](https://eval.in/39864)

Comment: You're right in the fact that if any line doesn't end, PHP will not know how to handle another statement/line. However in the scenario provided, `?>` effectively ends the line and as such isn't what's causing the error. _**YES**_, it absolutely makes sense to have the semicolons, in case you decide to add to the block of code, to say nothing of uniformity. But is it causing Anthony's problem? No.

Comment: @NickQ. regardless not everyone knows that, and in tons of questions around here you will see people committing small syntax errors which is better to teach/show good practices then poor coding, be it the problem or not. These small things may not be the case now but could be the case in the future so I would rather answer in a way it may prevent that. I also don't see a point on this argumentation but go ahead and enjoy yourself.

Comment: I think it's **great** to mention the best practices and get users on them. None the less, it's not the error itself. All I wanted to do was make sure that a user with the same error knew what _needed_ to be fixed and what their issue was (as that's what they were looking for)